# Making a selection in a select box and displaying the chosen answer into another

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help,

I am unsure as to how to go about the following:

If I select the color green into the first select box, I would need the selected option to be automatically selected into the 2nd select box.

How do you accomplish this using just javascript alone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span>Category:</span>
<br>
<select id="select1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE</option>
    <option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
    <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
</select>
<br>
<span>Your selection was:</span>
<br>
<select id="select2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE/option>
    <option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
    <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
</select><b></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont tell me you haven tried anything....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two select tags have same options:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');

select1.addEventListener('change', function(){
    select2.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28yzG/)

Note that this simple solution will be wrong for selects that have different options. In this case this will work:

```
select1.addEventListener('change', function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < select2.options.length; i++){
        if(select2.options[i].value === this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
            select2.options[i].selected = true;
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28yzG/1/)

Comment: The selects that I will be using will indeed have 2 different options. What's the code for that then? Looks like you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the options until you find the same value:

```
document.getElementById("select1").onchange = function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");

    //find the index in the second select
    for (var i = 0; i < select2.options.length; i++) {
        if (select2.options[i].value == selected) {
            select2.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HJm7E/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function doOnload() {
            var slt1 = document.getElementById("select1");
            var slt2 = document.getElementById("select2");
            slt1.onchange = function() {
                slt2.options[slt1.selectedIndex].selected = true;
            };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="doOnload()">
    <span>Category:</span>
    <br>
    <select id="select1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="RED">RED</option>
        <option value="BLUE">GREEN</option>
        <option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
        <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <span>Your selection was:</span>
    <br>
    <select id="select2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="RED">RED</option>
        <option value="BLUE">GREEN</option>
        <option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
        <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
    </select><b></b>
</body>
```